# The image slides on slick slider are not properly being displayed when reducing number of images via an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call that gets data from my back end. I use the data to draw canvas' and then I put those into a slide. When I press my search button it will get give me the amount of results that I have selected. However, when reducing the number of displayed results, for example I first limit my search to 20 and then to 10, my canvas' start to double up in divs and strange things tend to happen.

I tried using the following below to try and reset the slider when a new request is made.

```
$('.search').on('click', function () {
    slickReset.slick('setPosition');
});
```

Nothing happened though. I'm at a loss for how to get the slides to properly to display.

Below is my code in a snippet. Here is a gif to help understand what I'm trying to say. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJIU8.jpg

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I tried adding `$('#search-slider').html("");` to the beginning of my ajax call. This put the number of results for the second selection at the beginner of my slider, however I still had additional divs that were added to the end of those results.

P.S.
The snippet will not run as it is dependent on my backend data.

```js
$(function() {


  $('#search').click(function() {
    var nameVal = $('#shouhinName').val();
    var makerVal = $('#makerName').val();
    var categoryVal = $('#selectText').val();
    var sliderVal = $('#hideme').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "shelf/test",
      data: {


        shouhinName: nameVal,
        makerName: makerVal,
        selectText: categoryVal,
        best: sliderVal

      },
      success: function hi(j_data) {




        alert(j_data.url);
        
        let index = 0;
        const display = "table"; 
        const x = 0;
        const y = 0;
        var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ");
        document.body.style.display = display;

        for (const id of j_data.itemid) {

          $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', 0);

        }


        canvasArr = [];
        for (const image of j_data.url) {

          const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.setAttribute("name", "canvas");
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


         
          canvas.id = "option" + [index];

          var canId = canvas.id;
          var tooltip = j_data.tooltip;
         
          canvas.setAttribute('width', '75px');
          canvas.setAttribute('padding-top', '56.25%');
          canvas.setAttribute('object-fit', 'contain');
          canvas.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');
          // canvas.title = "hi";
          // console.log('#'+ canvas.id);

          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.setAttribute('data-html', 'true');
          div.id = j_data.itemid[index]; //image.slice(26, 34);


          
        
          drawImages(canvas);
        
          canvas.addEventListener("click", optionClicke, false);

        
          var text = j_data.tooltip[index];
         
          div.title = text;
          document.getElementById('search-slider').appendChild(div);
          document.getElementById(div.id).appendChild(canvas);
     
          index++;
         
        }

   

        function drawImages(canvas) {
         
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          const background = new Image();

       
          index = canvas.id.replace(/\D/g, "");

       
          if (j_data.url[index] !== '/check/assets/img/noimage.png') {
            background.src = "/check/assets/img/" + j_data.url[index];
          } else {
            background.src = '/check/assets/img/noimage.png'
          }


         
          background.onload = function() {

            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          };
    
        }

        function drawX(canvas, item) {
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         
          console.log(canvas.id);
     

          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(40, 75, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          ctx.lineWidth = 5;
          ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.stroke();
          console.log(item);
          hdnName.value = item;

        }


        function clear(canvas) {


          canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          drawImages(canvas);


        }

        function optionClicke(e) {
          log = true;
          const canvas = document.getElementsByName("canvas");
          var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ");
          let index = 0;


          for (const option of canvas) {
            if (log)
          
              log = false;
            if (e.target.id === option.id) {
           
              const item = j_data.itemid[index];
              console.log('draw' + item);
              console.log(index);
             
              drawX(option, item);

            } else {
         
              clear(option);
         
            }
            index++;
          }

        }



       

        // need to make the images line up
        $('.search-items').slick('unslick').slick('reinit');
        $(document).ready(function() {
         var slickReset = $('.search-items').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
            infinite: false, //true
            slidesToShow: 8,
            slidesToScroll: 8,
            arrows: true,
            centerMode: false,
            width: 200,
            prevArrow: $('.prev'),
            nextArrow: $('.next')
          });
        });

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("post error");
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
      },
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        console.log("fin");
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
 <div class="search-items" id="search-slider">
```

Comment: `for (const id of j_data.itemid) {

          $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', 0);

        }` should probably be `for(const id of j_data.itemid){

            $('#'+id).slick('slickRemove', 0);

        }`

Comment: When I try that the number of results displayed won't change. It will just stay at 20 and won't change if I pick 30 or 10 (or any number). I added in the slickRemove so that when the same number of results was selected it wouldn't double up the amount of slides.

Comment: I ended adding ``` for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
                                                                        
                                                                        $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', 0);
                                                                       // $('.search-items').slick('slickRemove', j_data.itemid.length);
                                                                        
                                                                  } ``` to my code and it fixed things.